# How to take a redirection URL

Tags: java, facebook, url, redirect

I have a problem with redirection, in my work I have to make a connection to a URL that automatically go to another URL at this point it takes the credential (username and password) and redirect to a URL that contains a parameter which need me. How can I take this parameter?

To be precise, I have to do this:

> Embed a Web browser with the URL https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize with your `client_id` and the type set to user_agent. Since your application is embedding a small window, you can trigger a compact "popup" version of the authorization dialog with the display parameter:
>
> ```
> graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?
>     client_id=...&
>     redirect_uri=www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&
>     type=user_agent&
>     display=popup
> ```
>
> After the user authorizes your application, we redirect the user back to `www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html` with the access token in the URL fragment: `www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=...&expires_in=...` Intercept the redirect above and read the access token out of the URL. Use the access token to fetch data from the Graph API on behalf of the user:
>   `graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=...`.

I need `access_token`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [apache http components httpclient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html) to do this,
it will automatically follow redirects

```
HttpClient client=new HttpClient();
GetMethod get=new GetMethod("graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=...&   redirect_uri=www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&type=user_agent&display=popup");
int status=client.exectueMethod(get);
```

Then you will have the information you need in the Location header of the response which you can access by using:

```
String location=get.getResponseHeader("location").getValue();
```

and parse the location-header  for the url fragment you want.

hope that helped

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it return me the String: [Lorg.apache.commons.httpclient.Header;@409cb0f4

What can I do???

Comment: did you forget get getValue()?